# Auth with MS Graph 2.0 in PHP

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api

I have PHP MS Grap 1.0 and everything working good, but now I try connect with my account in MS Graph 2.0 but I have error: Error getting user's inbox: invalid_grant Error getting user's inbox: /home/demon/domains/outlook.demosoft.pl/public_html/vendor/league/oauth2-client/src/Provider/GenericProvider.php

What I do wrong?

```
use Microsoft\Graph\Beta\GraphServiceClient;
use Microsoft\Graph\Beta\GraphRequestAdapter;
use Microsoft\Kiota\Abstractions\ApiException;
use Microsoft\Kiota\Authentication\Oauth\AuthorizationCodeContext;
use Microsoft\Kiota\Authentication\PhpLeagueAuthenticationProvider;
use Microsoft\Kiota\Http\GuzzleRequestAdapter;
use Microsoft\Graph\Core\Authentication\GraphPhpLeagueAuthenticationProvider;   
  
try {

        $tokenRequestContext = new AuthorizationCodeContext(
                'common',
                'client_id_xxxx',
                'secret_xxx',
                 'AuthCode',
                'http://localhost'
        );
        $scopes = ["User.Read", "Mail.Read", "Mail.Send", "Calendars.ReadWrite", "offline_access"];

         $authProvider = new PhpLeagueAuthenticationProvider($tokenRequestContext, $scopes);
        $requestAdapter = new GuzzleRequestAdapter($authProvider);
        
        $graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient($requestAdapter);

        $me = $graphServiceClient->me()->get()->wait();

        print_r($me);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print('Error getting user\'s inbox: ' . $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL);
        print('Error getting user\'s inbox: ' . $e->getFile() . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL);
    }
```